# Yii Searing and Sorting time slots from A table

Tags: sorting, search, yii

I am working on an Web App using Yii framework, In a form I give two times as input and  in the controller I should search for the available time slots between the  start time and the end time from another table which has all the 5 minutes interval time slots and here is my code which gets SQL error

```
                     $st = $_POST['Slots']['start_time'];
                    $et = $_POST['Slots']['end_time'];                         
                   $resslots = DoctorTimeSlots::model()->findAllByAttributes(
                            array(), 
                            "time_slots < $et AND >=$st", 
                            array('time_slots'=>time('H:i:s')));
```

Comment: What is the sql error you are getting?

Comment: DCbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid paameter number:
number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT *FROM
'doctor_time_slots' 't' WHERE 't'.'s_no'=:yp0 AND (time_slots<14:00:00 AND >=13:00:00), This is because of array(s_no=>10000) and now I get two time slots in the $resslots, not what I expected

Comment: hope my answer fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

You are missing column name in condition `"time_slots < $et AND >=$st",`

```
$resslots = DoctorTimeSlots::model()->findAllByAttributes(
        array(),
        $condition  = 'time_slots < :et AND time_slots >= :st',
        $params     = array(
                ':et' => $et, 
                ':st' => $st,
        )
);
```